# Adding options which both change behaviour and store an argument

Tags: python, argparse

Using the `argparse` module, is it possible to perform multiple actions for a given argument?

Specifically, I'd like to provide a `-l`/`--list` option with `nargs='?'` that will change the behaviour of the program from its main function to one of giving information about all possibilities in a set or about one particular possibility.

Normally there will be a namespace attribute that contains a function to be called after parsing; I would like the `-l` option to both change this attribute and optionally store its argument in a different attribute.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply implement your own `Action` subclass.  This basically looks like this:

```
class ListAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        setattr(namespace, 'list', values[0])
        do_something_completely_different()
```

The [argparse documentation](http://argparse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/add_argument.html#action) has more details.